# Event Setter issue of RadGrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

Hello Event Setter handler not working for MouseLeftButtonDown. Check xaml

```
<telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow">
                            <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="GridViewRow_MouseLeftButtonDown"></EventSetter>
                        </Style>
                    </telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
```

But it's working for PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown. Event is valid for both. No any error occurred during execution. What is the reason? And how to make handler command with mvvm? Actually we are using MVVM for my app. So I have two issue. Please provide need full solution. 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MouseLeftButtonDown is not valid with Event setter so please add MouseLeftButtonDown event with RowLoaded event. Something like will be as

```
 var row = e.Row as GridViewRow;
        if (row != null)
        {
           row.AddHandler(GridViewRow.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
      new MouseButtonEventHandler(GridViewRow_MouseLeftButtonDown), true);
        }
```

And method will be

```
 private void GridViewRow_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hi");
    }
```

It will be work fine.